# How to get the table row data in an input when I check a checkbox in that same row?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which have some fields like Service , amount , tax , action , I just want that if I tick on checkbox in that row , I want the table service data like Subscription charges  should be added in an input and when I tick on another rows checkbox this table data also should add in that input with a comma like subscription charges, registration fees ,  also when I untick that row checkbox , that table data like subscription charges, registration fees also should be removed in input

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Service </th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">tax</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Subscription Charges</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>500.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>90.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>registration fees</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>200.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>80.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Service </th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">tax</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>

<input type="text" name="services">
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this information first https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then repost your question.

Comment: i do not know where to start hence i do not know much about javascript

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it using jQuery is to first make sure we notice if a checkbox is changed, then go to the parent row, and find the first TD which should contain what you're out after. After all that, get the "target" element (ie. the input box at the bottom) and set it's value.

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
var value = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:first-child").text();
        var target = $("input[name=services]");
        
        target.val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Service </th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">tax</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>Subscription Charges</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>500.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>90.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>registration fees</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>200.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>80.00</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="checkbox" class="tot_amount" value="590.00" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="table2" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Service </th>
            <th scope="col">Amount</th>
            <th scope="col">tax</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>

<input type="text" name="services">
```